# Prove that $\sqrt{x^2+yz}+\sqrt{y^2+xz}+\sqrt{z^2+xy} \le 3$

Tags: inequality, polynomials, radicals, symmetric-polynomials, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Prove that 
$$\sqrt{x^2+yz}+\sqrt{y^2+xz}+\sqrt{z^2+xy} \le 3$$
for $x \ge 0$, $y \ge 0$, $z \ge 0$ and $x+y+z \le 2$.

**My work:** 
\begin{align*}
&\mathrel{\phantom{=}} \sqrt{x^2+yz}+\sqrt{y^2+xz}+\sqrt{z^2+xy}\\
&\le\sqrt3 \sqrt{x^2+yz+y^2+xz+z^2+xy}\\
&\le\sqrt3\sqrt{2x^2+2y^2+2z^2}=\sqrt6\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}.
\end{align*}

Comment: Since $\|U\|_2\leq  \|U\|_1$, you have here $\sqrt{x^2 +y^2 +z^2}\leq 2$ ; with your work you will have $2\sqrt{6}$ as upper bound ... I know, it is not enough :(

Comment: While applying Muirhead in between the second and third step,  I think there is a mistake.

Comment: Providing upper bounds on $\sum x^2$ based on $\sum x$ is usually the wrong path to take.  In fact finding the equality cases first and rigorously maintaining it at each step avoids wrong paths.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is enough to show the homogeneous inequality $\sum_{cyc} \sqrt{x^2+yz} \leqslant \frac32(x+y+z)$.  WLOG, let $x \geqslant y \geqslant z$.

Note by AM-GM, we have $\sqrt{x^2+yz} \leqslant \sqrt{x^2+xz} \leqslant x + \frac12z$.  *This type of AM-GM is motivated by noting $(1, 1, 0)$ is a solution for equality.*

Further by CS (or power means), we get
$$\sqrt{y^2+zx} + \sqrt{z^2+xy} \leqslant \sqrt{1+1} \sqrt{(y^2+zx)+(z^2+xy)}$$

Thus it is enough to show that
$$\sqrt2\sqrt{y^2+z^2+x(y+z)} \leqslant \frac12(x+3y+2z)$$
Simplifying, this is $(x-y-2z)^2+8z(y-z) \geqslant 0$ which is obvious.  Equality is when any two variables are equal and the third zero.

Comment: If you have $\sqrt{x^2+yz}\leq x+\frac{1}{2}z$ it is already finished, isn't it? Because the whole sum will be $\leq x+\frac{1}{2}z+y+\frac{1}{2}z+z+\frac{1}{2}x\leq 3$, no?

Comment: @Netchaiev That works only for one term unfortunately, as it depends on the order $x \geqslant y \implies x^2+yz \leqslant x^2+xz$.  It won't work on all the terms and if you do one more term like that, the last term will become too difficult to handle, and besides equality requires only one term to be zero.

Comment: Ok, I see, no miracle here :) Nice solution!

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\leqslant \frac12(x+\color{red}{3}y+2z)$ in the last inequality? – I could imagine that your approach can be generalized to solve https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3446608/42969.

Comment: @MartinR Yes, youre right, that’s possibly a typo as I seem to have used $3y$ to get the next line.  Corrected this. Haven’t checked the linked inequality yet.

Answer (score 1):

By C-S we have:
$$\left(\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{x^2+yz}\right)^2\leq\sum_{cyc}\frac{x^2+yz}{2x^2+y^2+z^2+yz}\sum_{cyc}(2x^2+y^2+z^2+yz).$$
Id est, it remains to prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{x^2+yz}{2x^2+y^2+z^2+yz}\sum_{cyc}(4x^2+yz)\leq\frac{9}{4}(x+y+z)^2,$$ which is
$$\sum_{sym}(x^8+2x^7y+9x^6y^2-23x^5y^3+10x^4y^4)+$$
$$+\sum_{sym}(5.5x^6yz+70x^5y^2z+79x^4y^3z+131.5x^4y^2z^2-97.5x^3y^3z^2)\geq0,$$
which is obvious after using following Schur:
$$2\sum_{cyc}(x^8-x^7y-x^7z+x^6yz)\geq0.$$